Check records exist in multiple tables and display common or not common records
I have data coming from multiple sources and I need to display whether it is common or not common.
select a.name,b.email, c.email,
case when a.[email] is not null then 'common' else 'not common' end as 'records_status_a&b'
from table1
full join table2 on a.email=b.email

The above code works fine if there are only 2 tables , If I add 3 or more tables then data gets changed and I get wrong output.
Also I don't want to create separate queries and I want to do this in a single query.
select a.name,b.email, c.email,
case when a.[email] is not null then 'common' else 'not common' end as 'records_status_a&b'
from table1
full join table2 on a.email=b.email
full join table3 on a.email=c.email

The last join is giving wrong results
Error is b.email filed will show more nulls than expected.
I'm using full join as I want to get all records

I've gone ahead and removed the conflicting tags here (SQL Server <> SQLite); please [edit] your question to (re)tag the actual (R)DBMS you are using. Why does tagging multiple RDBMS products make my question unclear?

"The last join is giving wrong results" "wrong" doesn't really tell us anything other than it's not what you want or expect. We don't know what your data looks like, nor the data you expect to get, so wrong is meaningless to us. Explain why it's wrong. Provide consumable sample data and expected results.

Are you aliasing the tables?

"The above code works fine if there are only 2 tables" I contest this. You reference columns from the tables (aliased as) a, b, and c, however, there are only two tables are defined in the FROM, and neither of those called/aliased a, b, or c.

Three-way merge/compare is usually not easy, so noone does it. But think about, you do:  a.email=c.email but this will only match table3 against table1, but if the value is missing there but exist in table2, you won't get proper match, you could try: ISNULL(a.email, b.email)=c.email perhaps, this gets kinda unwidely quick

A [mcve] would make this much clearer.

What is the rule for detecting 'common'?
